# OutputCache by Membership?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

I'm just reading about `OutputCache`, and I see how you can apply `VaryByParam` to change the cache based on parameters sent to the view, but I would like to change the cache based on both the parameters and the currently logged in user (using Asp.Nets default membership). I've been looking around, but I don't seem to be able to find a way to get this working.

Any suggestions on what I should try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use VaryByCustom. I implemented something like this:

```
[OutputCache(VaryByCustom="user")]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    return View();
}
```

and in Global.asax.cs

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
{
    if (arg == "user")
    {
        return context.Request.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? context.Request.User.Identity.Name : string.Empty;
    }

    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
}
```

Comment: in mvc 4 i believe the User property comes off of context, not Request.